# Scala avro4s, define SchemaFor for common trait?

Tags: scala, typeclass, avro4s

I am trying to define an [avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s) schema derivation for a common trait. Example

```
trait Event
case class UserCreated(name: String, age: Int) extends Event
case class UserDeleted(reason: String) extends Event
```

Derivation for the concrete classes seems straightforward:

```
given userCreatedSchemaFor = SchemaFor[UserCreated]
given userDeletedSchemaFor = SchemaFor[UserDeleted]
```

I would love to achieve something like this fake code:

```
given eventSchemaFor = new SchemaFor[Event] { 
  CASE (userCreated) => USE userCreatedSchemaFor
  CASE (userDeleted) => USE userDeletedSchemaFor
}
```

The [SchemaFor trait & object](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/master/avro4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/avro4s/SchemaFor.scala) expose some apply variants and 'factory' methods but I can't figure out a way to use them to my purpose. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @stefanobaghino is correct if you can seal the trait, but in my case I was interested in an unsealed trait. The solution to generate a schema was quite near - avro4s provides a `Schema.createUnion` which is great for this usecase.

The next problem you might have is encoding for serialization (after all we want to do something useful with this data). For that, the best way I found was the manual creation of an Encoder. Follows a scala-cli script that shows everything put together.

```
//> using scala 3.3.1
//> using dep com.sksamuel.avro4s::avro4s-core::5.0.9

import org.apache.avro.Schema
import com.sksamuel.avro4s.{AvroOutputStream, AvroSchema, Encoder, SchemaFor}
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import scala.util.Using

trait Event
case class UserCreated(age: Int) extends Event
case class UserDeleted(reason: String) extends Event
case class Envelope(name: String, event: Event) // <- here I use the trait

// individual schemas
given userCreatedSchema: Schema = AvroSchema[UserCreated] 
given userDeletedSchema: Schema = AvroSchema[UserDeleted]

given unionSchema: Schema = Schema.createUnion(
  AvroSchema[UserCreated],
  AvroSchema[UserDeleted],
)
given unionSchemaFor: SchemaFor[Event] = SchemaFor.from[Event](unionSchema)

val userCreated = UserCreated(18)
val userDeleted = UserDeleted("boring")
val envelopeUserCreated = Envelope("uc", userCreated)
val envelopeUserDeleted = Envelope("ud", userDeleted)

given encoderEvent: Encoder[Event] = (schema: Schema) => {
  case e: UserCreated =>
    summon[Encoder[UserCreated]].encode(userCreatedSchema)(e)
  case e: UserDeleted =>
    summon[Encoder[UserDeleted]].encode(userDeletedSchema)(e)
  case _ => throw new Exception()
}

object Main extends App:
  val byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  val jsonOutcome = Using(AvroOutputStream.json[Envelope].to(byteStream).build()) { aos =>
    aos.write(envelopeUserCreated)
    aos.write(envelopeUserDeleted)
    aos.flush()
    byteStream.toString
  }
  println(jsonOutcome)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can seal your trait, `sealed trait` hierarchies are supported out of the box (see the built-in type mappings in [this table](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s?tab=readme-ov-file#built-in-type-mappings)) and a few more notes on those [here](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s?tab=readme-ov-file#sealed-hierarchies).

The following works as expected without any further intervention:

```
import com.sksamuel.avro4s.SchemaFor

sealed trait Event
case class UserCreated(name: String, age: Int) extends Event
case class UserDeleted(reason: String) extends Event

val schemaForEvent = SchemaFor[Event]
val schemaForUserCreated = SchemaFor[UserCreated]
val schemaForUserDeleted = SchemaFor[UserDeleted]
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/mHxUsk30QXaemDMosbjxTQ/7).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Would you have a suggestion on how to approach this if sealing the trait wasn't an option? For context, the classes extending the trait are generated at compile time and in different files/folders.

Comment: If you are generating the classes, can you generate the codec as appropriate?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question sorry  What do you mean 'as appropriate'?

Comment: From what I understand in your comment, you have a trait defined and then you generate the classes inheriting from it. Since you are doing this, can you also generate the codec? From you original question it looks like you would only accept some sort of automatic derivation, but I'm not sure of the feasibility of automatic derivation for open hierarchies. However, if you could generate the additional codec, I believe that would be a feasible approach.

Comment: Ah thanks again for your time and sorry again for my poor understanding. Unfortunately I am not in control of trait/classes generation. From your insights, it seems to me that the best course for me is creating custom mappings using the Encoder and Decoder as mentioned here. https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-type-mappings . Will look deeper into this.